# Bootstrap navbar responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with bootstrap navbar. I have 3 links in left and 2 links in the right. I change the min screen width of the navbar to 600px to collapse but the problem is after 768px, the links stop moving/response to the screen change and the two links from the right are no longer visible before the navbar collapse. How can I fix this? Or what should I change in getbootstrap.com/customize/ to allow the navbar to further stick together after 768px. Thanks

Here is my navbar code

```
    <nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "navbar-header">
                <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#navbar" aria-expanded = "false" aria-control = "navbar">
                    <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class = "navbar-brand" href "/">Project Title</a>
            </div>

            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "navbar">
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href = "#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class = "divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li>
                        <p class = "navbar-btn">
                            <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">Login</a>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class = "navbar-btn">
                            <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default" role = "button" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#modal-sign-up" data-backdrop = "static" data-keyboard = "false">Sign up</a>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I used the http://getbootstrap.com/customize and change the @screen-sm in Media queries breakpoints to 600px. It the break point works fine but the navbar items is not working. Here is the picture

http://pasteboard.co/1bvNW8aE.png

asyou can see, the sign in button are getting hidden as I adjust the screen width, I want it to keep moving to the left. The end result is before the breakpoint the two buttons in the right are now hidden. How can I make it to move more to the left as I adjust the width? Thanks

Comment: Hi, it is always better to add code to illustrate what is happening so that you'll have better answers. Could you please add a bit code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for editing question, Here's what you want http://jsbin.com/nujime/1/

you either use [bootstrap Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to change

`@screen-sm-min` and `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable to your desired value (600 in this case),

`@screen-xs-max` and `@grid-float-breakpoint-max` to `yourValue - 1` (599 in this case),

and finally `@container-sm` to `yourValue - 40`(560 or something else)

or you can always use Bootstrap's Sass/Scss or less files to work with.

Comment: hi, I already done that, I change it to 600px and the break point for collapse is working. but the problem is when my screen width pass over 768px, the two button in the right stop moving. you can look at the image on my post.

Comment: Hi, now I understand what changes you needed, check updated answer, and upvote if works for you :)